# Is amp-facebook still experimental

Tags: amp-html

I'm having difficulty identifying what amp custom elements are going to be in production and what are experimental. Is amp-facebook still experimental?

Thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of active experiments is here: https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html

amp-facebook isn't yet in the validator but you can track it here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1486

Comment: Thanks, the commit https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/commit/2662a91f92f2acb1db2e41a7a6aac5c81d719355 now says it i in the validator but not on cdn. How long does that usually take? Is that the final stage for it being usable in production on launch? I'm just trying to understand if I should be trying to use this element or not right now. Steve

Comment: It's usually a week or two depending on if people find any serious bugs in the implementation.

Comment: It is now live in the validator.

Comment: Thanks very much ade